# Indexing in Sitecore 9.1 erroring out

Tags: solr, indexing

We have upgraded our solution to Sitecore 9.1 and Solr is upgraded to `7.2.1`.
Now while running indexing from index manager I am getting below error for few items:

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(:0)ocation WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] Crawler : UpdateRecursive UpdateItem failed - {xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character.
Source: System.Xml
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.GetXmlString(SaveOptions o)
   at SolrNet.Commands.AddCommand`1.ConvertToXml()
   at SolrNet.Commands.AddCommand`1.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.LowLevelSolrServer.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 group, Int32 groupSize)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddDocument(Object itemToAdd, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexOperations.ApplyPermissionsThenIndex(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexable version)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.UpdateItemVersion(IProviderUpdateContext context, Item version, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoUpdate(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(T indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, CrawlState`1 state)
```

I know there are few characters for which it is erroring out But There are plenty of items which has these characters. I can't remove these character.
Is there any way by which we can escape these characters in Solr.
In `Solr 5.1.0` there was no errors and indexing was successful.

Could anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Try https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18832/wildly-inconsistent-index-data-after-rebuilds